# Multiple UIView transformation animations, one repeats, the other does not

Tags: cgaffinetransform, catransform3d

I have a UIImageView whose instance has a repeating pulse-like animation.

I want this UIImageView to move with the force of the accelerometer. To do this I have added another animation, this time a translation.

However, once this translation happens, it stops the pulse, even when its not animating.

As these two animations are separate, I cannot use the `CGAffineTransformConcat` method to combine both animations.

I have tried adding one to the UIView and one to the layer property of the same UIView but it does not work.

I have also tried adding the movement directly to the frame of the view, however, this just causes my view to disobey the constraint constraining it to the center x of the superview.

Does anyone use/know of a work around to this?

Thanks as always!